# undefined al mostrar el objeto fileList con multer

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, multer

estoy tratando de poder subir varias imágenes al servidor mediante una aplicación con react, les dejo el código y luego explico mi error

```
const uploadFile = event => {
  const { files } = event.target;
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    setImagenes(files)
    const load = new FileReader()
    load.readAsDataURL(files[i])
    load.onload = res => {
      const { result } = res.target
      const obj = {
        url: result,
        data: files[i] 
      }
      setPreview(prevState => ([...prevState, obj]));
    }
  }
};
```

este es el evento que se ejecuta mediante el `onChange` del input `file`

```
const submit = event => {
event.preventDefault();
const form = new FormData()
form.append("titulo", nombre)
form.append("descripcion", descripcion)
form.append("precio", precio)
form.append("cantidad", cantidad)
form.append("marca", marca)
form.append("seccion", seccion)
form.append("image", imagenes)
Post("addArticle", form)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(imagenes)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.response)
  });
};
```

este es el evento que se ejecuta al enviar el formulario
//Ahora bien, la variable `imágenes` es quien contiene el Filelist y es lo que estoy enviando al backend con el `Fieldname` 'image', cuando yo quiero mostrar esto en el servidor mediante el `req.file` ese me devuelve undefined por consola, pero si mando `imágenes[0]` me devuelve el primer archivo por consola, yo lo que quiero es que solamente enviando el `imágenes` en el servidor me muestre los archivos mediante el `req.file`, esoy tratando de enviar no mas de 5 imágenes, pero estoy teniendo errores, básicamente lo que quiero hacer es que el `req.file` me muestre el `Filelist` entero pero no lo hace, me ayudan?

en la ruta para agregar artículos tengo la siguiente configuraron

```
router.route('/addArticle')
.post(upload.array('image'), createArticle)
```

si yo muestro esto por consola me devuelve esto

```
GET /api/addArticle 200 37.894 ms - 529
[Object: null prototype] {
  titulo: 'asdasd',
  descripcion: 'asdasd',
  precio: '444',
  cantidad: '44',
  marca: 'asdasd',
  seccion: 'asdasd',
  image: '[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File]'
}
[]
POST /api/addArticle 200 34.766 ms - 2
```

el el `req.body` me aparecen los objetos con la imagen pero no puedo accedes a ellos, pero cuando muestro el `req.files` me muestra por consola un array vació, pero las imágenes los datos de las imágenes no aparecen ahí no se por que necesito que me ayuden por favor